# rx-dom in a typescript app

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I am trying to use RxJS-DOM https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS-DOM and at the moment there are no official typings for this library.
So I am Using this type definition: https://gist.github.com/oliverw/a3ba9d804d848417fac4.
Then I am trying to import in like:

```
import * as Rx from 'rx';
Rx.DOM.ajax({...}); // to do a ajax call. 
                    // DOM is always undefined so ajax is never called
```

Can anyone help with this subject

Comment: assuming that you also have the rx.d.ts definitions included in your project it works just fine.

Comment: Yes I have, but it doesn't work.. DOM it's never resolved it's undefined so ajax method it's never called.

Comment: uhm.. is this happening at compile time or at run time?

Comment: Runtime. I need to do a sandbox and put it here.

Comment: how do you load the js file? the typescript definition file is only for the compiler to know how the js code looks like it does not contain any actual code and is not compiled to anything.

Comment: The file is being installed by nodejs and being bundle by gulp so it's in place when I inspect the page.

Comment: maybe the load order matters? :-/

Answer (score 0):

Type definitions have no effect on whether or not the library works. They only exist to help **YOU** find errors in **YOUR** code.

For now, just forget about the type definitions and make sure RxJS-DOM itself is installed correctly and your browser can find it.